# Swap x and y variables in lm() function in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, data-modeling, modeling, coefficients

Trying to get a summary output of the linear model created with the lm() function in R but no matter which way I set it up I get my desired y value as my x input. My desired output is the summary of the model where Winnings is the y output and averagedist is the input. This is my current output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Winnings ~ averagedist, data = combineddata)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-20.4978  -5.2992  -0.3824   6.0887  23.4764 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2.882e+02  7.577e-01 380.281  < 2e-16 ***
Winnings    1.293e-06  2.023e-07   6.391 8.97e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8.343 on 232 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1497,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.146 
F-statistic: 40.84 on 1 and 232 DF,  p-value: 8.967e-10
```

Have tried flipping the order and defining the variables using y = winnings, x = averagedist but always get the same output.

Comment: Can you supply some of your data so we can reproduce the problem? For example using `dput(combineddata)`

Comment: I posted the dput output here. Let me know if you can't get to it, thanks.
https://github.com/ebilkert/PGA-Moneyball

Comment: Try to restart R, or just clean your workspace and try again. Before you do that try to run a model using another (built in) dataset and check results. Use `summary(lm(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars))`. Does it still switch the variables?

Comment: Thanks for the data in `dput` format. I cannot reproduce this really strange error. Everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out @RuiBarradas. 

    summary(lm(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars))

Works as it should. I'll try and restart R and see if it works.

Comment: condensed to 

    summary(lm(Winnings ~ averagedist,combineddata))

and it worked. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Used `summary(lm(Winnings ~ averagedist,combineddata))` as an alternative way to set it up and that seemed to do the trick, as opposed the two step method:

```
str<-lm(Winnings ~ averagedist,combineddata)
summary(str)
```